# Removing parent node when it has children with the same name

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following input xml:

```
<DST>
   <PQ>
      <hostAddress>10.193.245.27</hostAddress>
   </PQ>
   <AWDSRVRunStoredProcedure xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
      <hostAddress>10.193.245.27</hostAddress>
      <storedprocedures>storedprocedurestwo</storedprocedures>
   </AWDSRVRunStoredProcedure>
   <DST>
      <test>I want this</test>
      <PQ>
         <hostAddress>10.193.245.27</hostAddress>
      </PQ>
      <AWDSRVRunStoredProcedure xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
         <hostAddress>10.193.245.27</hostAddress>
         <storedprocedures>storedproceduresone</storedprocedures>
      </AWDSRVRunStoredProcedure>
      <PQClaimSystemRequest>
         <request>request</request>
      </PQClaimSystemRequest>
   </DST>
</DST>
```

I want to remove the first root node `<DST>` and it's children except the second second `<DST>` . So , my resultant xml should be as follows.

```
 <DST>
      <test>I want this</test>
      <PQ>
         <hostAddress>10.193.245.27</hostAddress>
      </PQ>
      <AWDSRVRunStoredProcedure xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
         <hostAddress>10.193.245.27</hostAddress>
         <storedprocedures>storedproceduresone</storedprocedures>
      </AWDSRVRunStoredProcedure>
      <PQClaimSystemRequest>
         <request>request</request>
      </PQClaimSystemRequest>
   </DST>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following template :

```
<xsl:template match="DST[DST]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="DST"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Or if the rule applies for all elements (not specific to element named `DST`) :

```
<xsl:template match="*[*/name()=name()]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()=current()/name()]"/>
</xsl:template>
```